# JQuery: How to hide all blockquote elements that have only whitespace as content

Tags: jquery

This is fairly simple, I think, but I haven't been able to piece together the script that will do the job. I basically just want to be able to hide (i.e., 'display: none') any blockquote that has nothing but whitespace as its content.

I'd love to just use :empty, but it counts whitespace as 'content'. I've seen a few similar scripts, but I can't seem to put them together into a working whole.

EDIT: this is my current attempt...

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('blockquote').each(function() {
            if($(this).text().trim() === "") {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
    <article class="text">
        <p><span><a href="BLOG_URL">BLOG_NAME</a></span>:</p>
        <blockquote>
            <blockquote><!--This is what I'm trying to hide.-->
            </blockquote><!--Darned arbitrary line breaks-->
            <p>TEXT HERE/p>
        </blockquote>
        <p>More text here...</p>
    </article>
```

Comment: Try posting what you've come up with, at least.

Comment: where is your work ?

Comment: Try using something like this `if($.trim($('blockquote').text()) === "") {}`. Post your attempted code and we can help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go. Edited OP to post my most recent attempt.

Comment: Tried this, but it wasn't working either: `$(document).ready(function() {
        if($.trim($('blockquote').text()) === "") {
                $('blockquote').hide();
        }
    });`

Comment: @JoelFrancis Can you post your markup as well.

Comment: The entire document? This is for a Tumblr theme, so the webpages are dynamically generated.  I'll post a typical markup framework where this *should* be coming into play as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking your markup, it is hard to tell you what is wrong. This is my simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLj1ehj2/2/) and it is working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('blockquote').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().trim() === "") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I hear you. Posted some markup sample, but I'm not even sure there should be anything wrong... Maybe tumblr disables jQuery somehow.